# Periodic Laplace transform

Tags: laplace-transform, periodic-functions

[Here's the questions and the graph](http://db.tt/QYw8iDaS)

I've been struggling with this since Thursday and this is due today. 
I need help on problems a and b.

For a, the question is:
"Write $f(t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \theta(t-a_n)f_n(t-a_n)$."

I think I finally made some headway.

After writing some piecewise functions:
$$f(t) = 
\begin{cases}
1-\frac 2\pi &\text{if}& 0 < t < \pi \\
-1 + \frac 2\pi &\text{if}& \pi < t < 2\pi\\
1-\frac2\pi(t-2\pi) &\text{if}& 2\pi < t < 3\pi\\
-1 + \frac2\pi (t-3\pi) &\text{if}& 3\pi < t <4\pi\\
\end{cases}$$

I got
$$f(t) = 1- \frac2\pi t + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \theta(t-\pi)\frac4\pi (t-\pi)$$
(where $\theta$ is the U - for unit function - in the original question.)

But should there be a $k\pi$ somewhere, or a $n\pi$ or something? How far am I from completing part a correctly?

Any guidance on parts

b: Use the Laplace transforms to solve the I.V.P. $y''+4y'+5y=f(t), y(0)=0, y'(0)=0.$ Write $Y(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \theta(t-a_1)Y_n(t-a_n)$

c: Graph $Y(t)$ for $0<t<4\pi$.

or d: Predict $\lim {t>\infty}|Y(t)|$.

would be appreciated as well. 
This is due in about 9 hours and is a take-home quiz for a differential equations class where we're allowed to use any resources we have (short of paying) to solve the problem.

Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: Please make the question self-contained.

Comment: Fixed as much as I could - the original graph remains on the link, though....

Comment: What is the unit function? Is it equal to $0$ if $t<0$, and $1$ if $t\geq0$? Also, the sum you wrote does not converge:
$$
\sum_{n\geq0} \theta(t-\pi)(t-\pi)4/\pi=
\theta(t-\pi)(t-\pi)\sum_{n\geq0} 4/\pi
$$
/edit : Furthermore, be sure to check the first two cases in $f(t)$, what you wrote does not depend on $t$.

Comment: Why the upvotes?